# calling an angular function when an option is selected from list

Tags: angularjs, onmouseclick

input type="text" placeholder="" ng-autocomplete ng-keyup="addDeliveryAreas($event)" ng-model="deliveryareas.search" details="details" options="options"

I am using ng-autocomplete directive. 
https://github.com/wpalahnuk/ngAutocomplete
I want to call an angular function when an address is selected from option list

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the ng-change directive. [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) The function you will bind to it will be called everytimes a change to the ng-model occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several things.. ngblur="myfunction()" worked for my use case